# Paying for making another's pot treif?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, torts-damages

Is one halachically required to pay for accidentally making another person's [earthenware pot](https://www.outorah.org/p/86382) (or any *kli* with a questionable *kashering* status) non-kosher if the pot owner holds that he may not *kasher* earthenware? (or any *kli* with a questionable *kashering* status)

Of course, CYLOR if this case becomes practical.

Comment: see Gittin 5:4.